# Limit calculation using L'Hopital's Rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, limits

From an old exam qualifier, one of the questions is:
Show that 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log(k)} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n}\int_{2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log(x)}dx = 1
\end{equation*}

I can show the first equality, but I'm having a problem with the second equality.

By monotonicity, 
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\frac{1}{\log(k+1)} &\le \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{\log(x)}dx \le \frac{1}{\log(k)} \Rightarrow \\
\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\log(k+1)} &\le \int_{2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log(x)}dx \le \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\log(k)} \Rightarrow \\
\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log(k)} - \frac{1}{\log(2)}&\le \int_{2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log(x)}dx \le \sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log(k)} - \frac{1}{\log(n)} \Rightarrow \\
\frac{\log(n)}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log(k)} - \frac{1}{\log(2)}&\le \frac{\log(n)}{n}\int_{2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log(x)}dx \le \frac{\log(n)}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log(k)} - \frac{1}{\log(n)} \Rightarrow \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log(k)} - \frac{1}{\log(2)}&\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n}\int_{2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log(x)}dx \le \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log(k)} - \frac{1}{\log(n)}.
\end{alignat*}
This gives the first equality.

For the second equality, I try using L'Hopital's rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and get:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n}\int_{2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log x}dx &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_{2}^{n}\frac{1}{\log x}dx}{\frac{n}{\log(n)}} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\log n}-\frac{1}{\log 2}}{\frac{\log(n)-1}{\log(n)^{2}}} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n)-1}-\frac{1}{\log 2}\frac{\log(n)^{2}}{\log(n)-1}\\
&= 1 - \infty
\end{alignat*}

Is there an error in this calculation?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $\int_{2}^{t}\frac{1}{\log(x)}dx$ is $\frac{1}{\log(t)}$ not $\frac{1}{\log(t)}-\frac{1}{\log(2)}$. That correction allows the limit to tend to $1$.